# PowerShell Asking to Enter Value

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a test SQL script I'm trying to run in the PowerShell using SQLPlus. The path to the script looks like this:

```
@C:\&DI\test.sql
```

When I run this, I get the prompt

```
Enter value for di:
```

If I input &DI, everything works. I'd rather avoid any prompt. I've tried a bunch of different combinations of quotes, but haven't had any luck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape ampersands, semicolons, and curly braces in command-line powershell params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142786/how-to-escape-ampersands-semicolons-and-curly-braces-in-command-line-powershel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing a SQL*Plus prompt, not a PowerShell prompt.

SQL*Plus uses an ampersand to identify [substitution variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) by default. When it sees `@C:\&DI` it looks for a defined substitution variable called `DI`, and as it doesn't find one ir prompts you for it.

You can change the character it uses, or just disable that functionality, bu issuing:

```
set define off
```

before your `@` run command.

```
SQL> @C:\&DI\test.sql
Enter value for di: xyz
SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\xyz\test.sql"
SQL> set define off
SQL> @C:\&DI\test.sql
SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\&DI\test.sql"
SQL>
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073).