# How to pass strings to powershell from cmd with ampersands in values?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

In windows CMD, I want to run a powershell script and pass string params, which have quotes and ampersands in the params.

```
U:\Desktop>PowerShell .\post "http://domain/api/app?pLanguage=en-US\"&\"pCompanyID=816" "{\"Message\":\"test message - please ignore\"}"
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

'\"pCompanyID=816"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: To start with you should use `PowerShell -Command ""`. In between those doublequotes, enter the command line you'd normally enter at a powershell prompt, and we'll take it from there!

Comment: Try to [escape](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the `&` like `^&`...

Answer (score 1):

From another question on this site - [How to escape ampersands, semicolons, and curly braces in command-line powershell params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142786/how-to-escape-ampersands-semicolons-and-curly-braces-in-command-line-powershel)

Wrap your command line strings in nested double and single quotes - e.g. "'[somestring]'".

In your specific case:

```
C:> powershell .\post "'http://domain/api/app?pLanguage=en-US&pCompanyID=816'" "'{\"Message\":\"test message - please ignore\"}'"
```