# Escape semicolon in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, escaping

I have major difficulties escaping a semicolon in my powershell script. 
At first I open up a excel application, create a workbook and worksheet. So far so good.
I can write to cells but when I try to write a semicolon to a cell, an error (HRESULT: 0x800A03EC) occurs.

```
$rootsheet.Cells(5,5)='=SUM(A1;A2)'
```

For example the semicolon in this SUM-function causes the error.
I tried various possible escape format but nothing seems to work.
The solutions in the following articles do not apply in this case:
[escape-ampersands-semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142786/how-to-escape-ampersands-semicolons-and-curly-braces-in-command-line-powershel/36143995) 
[what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell)

Comment: A guess, but try `'=SUM(A1,A2)'`. Excel may require you to use the comma as a separator when writing the formula programmatically.

Comment: @BigBen, that's correct. I just gave it a try. Seems PowerShell needs you to input formulas with the `,` as a parameter seperator. Note, Excel will translate this back to the semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `,` as the formula separator instead of `;` when inputting a formula programmatically. Excel will "translate" this back to the semi-colon:

```
'=SUM(A1,A2)'
```